# save filters, no data WebDataRocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, webdatarocks

I have a table that receives a .JSON.
I have created some filters and I would like to save them but without saving the information that I received at that time with the filter.
I already tried:

```
pivot.getData({},
    function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
);
```

Too

```
var report = pivot.getReport();
console.log(report);
```

by last

```
pivot.save({filename:'reporte.json',embedData : false });
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve what you need:

1. You can still use:

   `var report = pivot.getReport();`

   the data information is stored in report["dataSource"]. In such a
   case, you can easily remove the unnecessary object the following
   way:

   `delete report["dataSource"];`

   After that, the JSON config is saved as a file to the disk using
   the following approach:
   [JavaScript: Create and save file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file).

   The disadvantage of such a solution is that you cannot use the saved
   JSON config to restore the view since it lacks the data part. You will need to add the "*dataSource*" part when you decide to restore
   the view. Therefore, the solution that described below looks better
   for me.
2. You can create a web service that returns the data file or simply put the JSON data file to the server. In such a case,
   WebDataRocks will load the data for you. Then, when you decide to
   save the config, only the link to the data will be saved to config.

   Here is the reference to docs:
   https://www.webdatarocks.com/doc/data-source-object/. The
   "*filename*" property represents the link which leads to your data
   file.

   In such a case you don't need any additional customization for the
   "Save" functionality. You can use a default one. Then it is easy to restore the view using the saved config.